# .NET 6 app hosted on the kubernetes returns 499 in 4% of cases

Tags: c#, .net, kubernetes

I have simple application that has 2 endpoints, one of the endpoints uses data in memory, second uses Redis cache (IDistributedCache). This application is hosted on the kubernetes. Works on .net 6, has about 40 req/s and works on 2 instances. The application responses usually in 1-6 milisecnds (95 percentile is 6 ms).

The problem is, that when I declare cpu request 200 Mi and limit 400Mi, then about 4% requests returns 499 code (my clients have timeout 500ms). The `kubectl top pods` shows that both apps use less than 50m CPU and 170Mi of memory. When I set request 500Mi and limit 2500Mi then it works without timeouts, but for the lowe limits (eg. 1500Mi) works without timeouts just for 5min-5h - I cannot find correlation.

The application is published externally by the nginx. I sue this image `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0`. The same situation is with `alpine`.

I have no idea why this app requires so many CPU limit? I don't see throttling in grafafna when I set limits on 1000Mi.

What can be reason of this problems?
Thanks.

Comment: So Nginx is your ingress controller? Have you checked the logs of your app to see if it is the one responsible for the 499 or if it's Nginx?

Comment: Yes, Nginx is my ingress controller. All the time upstream response was big and when I changed CPU for the application pod the problems finished, so I the only one option is a problem around the pod or inside.

Comment: I've found the solution of this problem. I've changed number of threads by ThreadPool .SetMinThreads(4, 4). Default value was (1,1)